# How to store the variables output inside a function during concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor from concurrent.futures

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing

I am currently trying to store the output obtained in a function during multiprocessing by using concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor from concurrent.futures built a library of python3 storing the variable as a global variable. But the variable output gets deleted once the process is over.
Does anyone has faced the same issue?

Reference:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor

Comment: You need to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to precisely demonstrate what it is you are trying to do but is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=7) as executor:
    fxReturn = executor.submit(your_function)
    fxReturn.result()
```

fxReturn will store return value of `your_function` but to access it you need to use `result()`